# Passing a pointer to an array in a struct

Tags: c

What's wrong in my function 'front'?
I want to pass the pointer to an specific line in my array to read/edit it.

```
struct queue
{  
  char itens[LN][CL];
  int front,rear;
}; 


char *front(struct queue * pq)
{
  return pq->itens[pq->front+1][0];
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're currently returning a single `char`, not a pointer to a row.  Take off the `[0]`:

```
char *front(struct queue *pq)
{
    return pq->itens[pq->front+1];
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this will work with the two dimensional array? (Update: It does)

Answer (score 5):

You are accessing the char and not using its address. Use:

```
&(pq->itens[pq->front+1][0])
```

Note that the outer parens are optional.

Comment: This answer is the same as mine and will work just as well.  It's just more typing.

Comment: @CarlNorum Yes, indeed. I guess it's a question of taste.

Comment: @gzm0 the parentheses are unnecessary